# iOS sdk printing multiple images

Tags: ios, image, airprint

i'm working on my first app and now i'm trying to implement air print in a customised version of the "Autoscroll" Apple sample code. basically i present the user with the print controller from a custom button and then they should have the choice of printing the image they have selected. autoscroll works in this way: you have 2 scroll views in a view controller a big one that allows zooming and a small one that slides in/out by tapping once on the big one. the small scroll view contains a number of thumbnails that are loaded in the big scroll view on selection by tapping. so far by studying the print photo sample code i manage to print one image; the first one loaded when the view controller is presented. i'm aware that multiple ready to print images have to in an array, but the example in the printing and drawing guide has 1 line of code and talks about an array of image views. the images i need to print go inside a scroll view.

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode as a sample source code that u can use to archive what u want, since it as already some of the features that you want to implement.

The name of the project is ScrollViewSuite and you can download it from here: [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: read the question i am using that and i need to do what the rest of the question says.